# Is it possible to convert shape keys to rigged bones?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, shape-keys

I have a model with some shape keys, But the program its made for only works with rigs/ armature. Is there a way to convert the shape keys into bones I can then move a certain amount to get the same effect. Everything I find on this topic just refers to using bones as drivers

Comment: I don't think its possible for the general case.

Comment: There probably is a way to make a script capable of creating bones that recreate the motion of a shapekey, but I haven't heard of any existing script. And just thinking vaguely about it, I don't think there is a way to do it both accurately and without making a messy rig with tons of bones for each shape.

Comment: Great idea. i´ve never seen anything like it tho. What software are you exporting for? If it´s for Unity you might be able to combine shape key animation and bones in the NLA Editor and export the combined animation as fbx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while there are no plugins so far to do it, if it is a simple shape key like moving a group of vertices along a straight path you can manually rig it with bones